# Blog-like single element pages with TYPO3 / TemplaVoila

Tags: typo3, typoscript, realurl, templavoila

I have a blog-like part of an page using TYPO3 / TemplaVoila. There are articles that should show up summarized on a single page, but have their own pages / URLs each one too.

However, having the editors add a page AND a flexible content element for each entry is complicated.

So is it possible by some typoscript to have a page, showing a single content element from some other page, sporting a proper URL without having to setup an extra page for each element?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is doable without TV and with other records than tt_content.

e.g.: ext:news does it: the content are news records, which are shown with plugins in list- and detail-mode.

Of course you can reinvent the complete logic of such an extension so you can do it with tt_content records, which could be stored in the usual way scattered on multiple pages.
But the logic is clearer if there only is one page (or very few pages which represent some categorization) where special records are stored.
Plugins would be configured to show only selected records (from one category, which are marked top, which are current, ...) and you have one page (one for all and not for each news one) where the records are shown in detail.
Also each has it's own URL, either with URL-parameter (by default) or you configure realurl (or similar) to build a "real url" from news title (and uid).

Comment: I know tt_news, however it does not use TemplaVoila templates and so cannot use our main template with TemplaVoila mapping procedures but must be mapped via TypoScript manually, what our web designer doesn't like of course.

Comment: `ext:news`  not `ext:tt_news`. and if a plugin has dependencies to the page template something is wrong. I don't know any plugin which depends in any kind on the rendering of the page object. for the page template any content (either Text, Image or plugin) should be a block (mostly `<div>`) and the plugin can decide on it's own how to render/ what kind of templating it uses. If your web designer insists on such a dependency give him a kick, Using TV today is another reason to look for another web designer.

Comment: Site is existing, migrating from TV to another template mapping system would be a mess. Besides this, I don't know any extension that would give interactively mapped templates (like with TV) that can be used for _any_ other extension. Is there one?